# Play Framework / Dependent Future Composition

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I am trying to do several dependent Slick/DB calls and then display the resulting data within a twirl template.

```
def show(slug: String) = Action.async { implicit rs =>

    for {

      f <- fooDAO.findBySlug(slug)  // f is of type Option[foo]
      fid <- f.flatMap(a => a.id.map(b => b)) // fid is of type Long
      b <- barDAO.findByFooId(fid) // b is of type Seq[bar] 

    } yield {

        f.map {
          case Some(f) => Ok(views.html.foobar(f, b))
          case _ => NotFound
        }

      }
  }
```

I first need to get the "ID" to then be able to query other relevant data. The compiler is now producing this error:

```
play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[play.api.mvc.Result]]
 required: Option[?]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are several things I don't follow in your code. 1. why `f.flatMap(a => a.id.map(b => b))` instead of `f.flatMap(_.id)`; 2. why the comments use variable names different from referenced code; 3. what do you expect from the last case mapping in the `yield` block: are you aware that the `NotFound` alternative is never reached? `case f =>` will match every value  and bind it to a variable named `f`.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup with the variable names. I corrected this now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental flaw in your code, in that you're mixing in the same comprehension an `Option` and a `Seq`

A for-comprehension is expected to work on the same "container" type, which will be the resulting representation of the `yield`

e.g. if you combine several `Option`s you get an `Option`, if you combine `Seq`s you get a `Seq`.

In this case you can overcome the problem by converting the `Option` (foo) to a `Seq` (which will be empty if the foo is `None` and have 1 element if not).

The end result would be

```
val results: Seq[(Foo, Bar)] =
  for {
    f <- fooDAO.findBySlug(slug).toSeq  // f is of type Seq[Foo]
    b <- barDAO.findByFooId(f.id) // b is of type Seq[Bar] 
  } yield (f, b)
```

But I guess this is not what you need. I suppose you want to get all `Bar`s associated with the retrieved `Foo`, if any, and present it with your template. If no `Foo` is present for the `slug`, you want a `NotFound`.

We can do it like this

```
def show(slug: String) = Action.async { implicit rs =>

  val f = fooDAO.findBySlug(slug)  // f is of type Option[Foo]

  f.fold(
    NotFound,
    foo => Ok(views.html.foobar(foo, barDAO.findByFooId(foo.id))
  )

}
```

You can make it more explicit by defining a supporting method

```
def show(slug: String) = Action.async { implicit rs =>

  def barsOf(f: Foo): Seq[Bar] = barDAO.findByFooId(f.id)

  val f = fooDAO.findBySlug(slug)  // f is of type Option[Foo]

  f.fold(
    NotFound,
    foo => Ok(views.html.foobar(foo, barsOf(foo))
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky understanding what you're trying to achieve here, but if the whole thing is predicated on the `findbySlug` returning a `Future[Option[Foo]]` and the eventual outcome being a `NotFound` if that `Option` is a `None`, then your `yield` should probably just be:

```
   ...
 } yield {
  f.fold(NotFound)(foo => Ok(views.html.foobar(foo, b)))
}
```

`Option[T]` is a fantastic type for data-retrieval and control-flow, but [pattern-matching on it is almost never the right approach](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/). The use of `fold` feels nicely succinct for the task.